# How to concatenate env variable to string in YAML file

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, serverless

I have a serverless.yaml file and I'm trying to concatenate a variable from my .env file to part of a string but haven't been successful. Here is an example:

```
.env file:
PHOTO_BUCKET=Images
```

```
.yaml file:
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::"${env:PHOTO_BUCKET}"/*"
```

I have also tried

```
Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${env:PHOTO_BUCKET}/*"
```

The error that I get is `can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed`. I'd appreciated it if someone can show me the right direction.

Comment: Are you getting the same error with the alternative string, because that should work.

Comment: @flyx get this error in my serverless deployment " A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:PHOTO_BUCKET' could not be found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the `A valid environment variable to satisfy the declaration 'env:PHOTO_BUCKET' could not be found` error, please make sure you have the required [dotenv plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-dotenv-plugin) installed and include it to your yaml:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

To fix the `can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed` error, please remove the inner pair of quotation marks from the resource:

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - "s3:PutObject"
      - "s3:GetObject"
    Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${env:PHOTO_BUCKET}/*"
```